# Want to read url which display on the web browser

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I want to read URL which displays on the web browser. And also want to show that URL on my current tab textView.could you please give me some coding solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
window.location.href
```

```js
console.log(window.location.href)
```

Comment: `window.top.location.href` would be correct regarding the "which displays on the web browser". Since we do not know the context it gets used in.

Comment: @Lain thanks for the solution. but I need to read another tab URL EX: I opened two tabs and I need to read second tab URL from the first tab

Comment: @DevPri: That merely works if you use `window.open()` to open them and if those tabs are on the same domain.

Comment: @Lain it is different domain

Comment: @DevPri: Nothing you can do. It is not possible.